# Best socket for 2mm multimeter probe

Tags: multimeter, test-equipment, socket

I'm looking for a 2mm jack suitable for plugging a multimeter probe into (the probe end of the cable, not the meter end).  I believe a 2mm banana jack would work and I've narrowed things down to two options: one with a machined socket and one with a stamped socket.  Would a machined socket work for a non-banana plug or should I go with the stamped one?  Is there a better option?

The specific parts I'm looking at are the Radiall R921 926 000 and R921 936 000 ([datasheet for both](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/516/radiall_radl-s-a0003608112-1-1746778.pdf), see page 23 "INSULATED BANANA SOCKETS").

Comment: This is why straight probes aren't the only probes that exist. Use clip probes and test point hooks. Or unplug the probe and use a banana patch cable. No idea why you want to use a straight probe in this situation.

Comment: @DKNguyen This is going to be mounted on the end of a narrow probe containing additional components (shaped like a pen).  I want to use a jack so that the meter lead has a solid connection while probing.  Using a 4mm jack (and using a patch cable) cable is an option but mechanically would be a sub-par choice.

Comment: If it's not a test assembly then yeah, clips and testpoints won't work. I fail to see how straight probes shoved into a socket are more mechanically secure over a banana patch cables (or any other solution for that matter). Another option is BNC connectors.

Comment: Probes are… for probing. Not meant as plugs. Their diameter due to plating is not tightly controlled, they are huge relative to the pin size, etc. Why do you think you need to do it this way?

Answer (score 1):

Most meter probe tips are compatible with 2mm banana jacks.

Due to the length of the probe handle there is an increased risk of accidental damage. It's probably better to use cables with the correct connector on each end instead.

Answer (score 0):

I tried fitting a meter test point into the female terminal of a molex connector. It works!

There is a bit of friction, and could be more with a slight bending with a pin tool. So I would say that a stamped fitting allows you to adjust the friction as needed.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>**Note: Answering my own question.  If someone posts a more detailed or useful answer I'll accept their answer**</sup>

After some more research I found that what I'm looking for are called ***Pin Tip Jacks*** (or just ***Tip Jacks***).  They seem to come in two varieties: "formed" (which I suspect are very similar to "stamped" banana jacks) and machined ones with internal spring contacts.  Here are a couple of examples of the latter:

Mentioned in the specifications: 
[image: Text mentioning spring] 
<sup>Source: [Cinch 105-1041-001 datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/643/pi-CCS-JOHN-105-1041-001-1289602.pdf)</sup>

Shown in the technical drawing: 
[image: Cross section showing springs] 
<sup>Source: [Pomona 3542 datasheet](https://www.pomonaelectronics.com/sites/default/files/d3542_100.pdf)</sup>

Some probes also have a threaded section allowing for a very secure connection but unfortunately [the thread does not seem to be standardized](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/testgear/screw-on-hook-clip/)<sup>1</sup>.

[image: Threaded probe tips]
<sup>Source: Own work</sup>

<sup>1</sup> The probes shown above (UEI) appear to have M4-0.70 threads; others (Probe Master, Fluke) use 8-32.  Undoubtedly there are other variations.